# com.sun.xml.rpc.tools.ant.Wscompile cannot be found

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, jax-rpc

I need to use a service at http://mihansmscenter.com/webservice/?wsdl so i should use jax-rpc i add jax-rpc plugin to my netbeans then

```
righ click on my project > New > Web service client > 

and set:

WSDL URL:http://mihansmscenter.com/webservice/?wsdl
project: my project
package: smsService
client style: JAX-RPC Style
```

but when click finish after about 40% of task completed there is an error:
com.sun.xml.rpc.tools.ant.Wscompile cannot be found

Answer (score 1):

[This fix](http://old.nabble.com/ant-task-Wscompile-cannot-be-found-in-NB-6-td14193353.html) from Roy Damman worked for me.

Edit:

Roy Damman said on that thread:

> The bug seems to be in /nbproject/project.properties:
>
> Change:
>
> `wscompile.classpath=${wscompile.tools.classpath}:${j2ee.platform.wscompile.classpath}`
>
> To:
>
> `wscompile.classpath=${wscompile.tools.classpath}:${j2ee.platform.wscompile.classpath}:${javac.classpath}`

Maybe [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20110625235623/http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/ant-task-Wscompile-cannot-be-found-in-NB-6-td3006152.html) link stays up.

Comment: Please don't link to forums. This is an enormously frustrating broken window. Provide self-contained answers.