# How do I enable "JAX-RPC Web Services" plugin in NetBeans 8.0

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, wsdl, netbeans-8

I'm trying to build a WS client from an RPC (allegedly) encoded WSDL service at

```
https://www.fbo.gov/ws/fbo_api.php?wsdl
```

I'm using right click on Web Service Project, create New Web Service Client.

The wsdl is rpc encoded. To process this wsdl install the "JAX-RPC Web Services" plugin.

I tried manually installing the following plugins

```
modules/org-netbeans-modules-websvc-jaxrpc16.nbm
modules/org-netbeans-modules-websvc-jaxrpckit.nbm
modules/org-netbeans-modules-websvc-jaxrpc.nbm
modules/org-netbeans-modules-websvc-registry.nbm
```

But still no dice.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 9):

Actually, JAX-RPC is an old version of SOAP and which is overtaken by JAX-WS. That is why netbeans does not provide this plugin in default version.

You can install the plugin by adding another plugin directory.

Go to Tools -> plugins -> Settings -> Add and set URL as http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

After adding this URL you will be able to see JAX-RPC plugin under plugin section and install that.

Comment: I followed your instructions and now I can't open netbeans 8

Comment: @FrancisAngelinoGonzalesTell happened to me the same in netbeans 7 did you get solve?

Comment: same to me. I can't open the netbeans now after doing this. It crashes during start time when it loading modules

Comment: Plugin installed. But same error. Netbeans 8.1. Then generated the classes from eclipse.

Comment: Following the comments in https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=238447, the new URL for the above repository is http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

Answer (score 0):

by the way, another way to install the plugins is doing it manually (mentioned by the original poster as something that was already attempted). at the time of writing this, the NetBeans plugin/module files (*.nbm) can be downloaded from [this location](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/extra/).

this is also applicable to Apache NetBeans 9. (in fact, I tried this on NetBeans 9 and hope this works on 8.1/8.2 too). the needed modules are mentioned by the original poster, and in this [here post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581537/cannot-find-any-jax-rpc-plugins-for-netbeans) from stackoverflow (the location of netbeans repository seems to change all the time) - myself, I downloaded all the org-netbeans-modules-websvc-*.nbm files, just to be on the safe side.

Netbeans 9 loads properly.
one more thing - i was dealing with a project made with netbeans 6.8 - i had to modify a line in project.properties (wscompile.classpath), as pointed out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460099/com-sun-xml-rpc-tools-ant-wscompile-cannot-be-found)
thanx.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone , having trouble with the plugins of JAX RPC on any version of netbeans (netbeans 11 in my case) and JAx-RPC , some good fellow prepared a great maven project for creating the necessary Classes and packages for a RPC WSDL

https://github.com/anomen-s/maven-jaxrpc-plugin