# Cannot find any JAX-RPC plugins for netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I search in the Plugin manager in netbeans, but I cannot find any available plugin when I tried to search for JAX-RPC.

Comment: Is there any reason that you don't want to use JAX-WS? JAX-RPC is just about a deprecated technology

Comment: Old API is RPC encoded.. and I have to connect to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the netbeans plugins in this link
http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/6.9/uc/m1/dev/modules/extra/

download this nbm's
org-netbeans-modules-websvc-jaxrpc.nbm

org-netbeans-modules-websvc-jaxrpc16.nbm

org-netbeans-modules-websvc-jaxrpckit.nbm

org-netbeans-modules-websvc-registry.nbm

hope this will help.